# How to make menu items appear on mouseover with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onmouseover

I am developing a website with a mobile menu where three underlying elements should appear when hovering over another menu item (not a parent!)

I have tried css but that was not possible without altering the html structure, so I left that for now. I also tried `onclick` function but the mobile menu disappears after a click so that doesn't work either. Therefore, `onmouseover` javascript would be preferable.

The javascript code I have so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementsByClassName("holder").onmouseover = function(){mouseOver()};
    document.getElementsByClassName("holder").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
    function mouseOver() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("helper").style.display=="block";}
    function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("helper").style.display=="none";}
</script>
```

The html is as follows:

```
<ul class="mm-listview">
<li class="holder menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#">Holder</a></li>
<li class="helpers menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-icon"><a href="https://example.com/">Example</a></li>
<li class="helpers menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-icon"><a href="https://example.com/">Example</a>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the console to see if there are errors? **getElementsByClassName** will return an array with all elements with class "helper". You need to change the display of each of those elements.

Comment: you can't "hover" on a mobile

Answer (score 0):

```
Modified HTML below.

<ul class="mm-listview">
<li id="holder"><a href="#">Holder</a></li>
<li id="helper1"><a href="https://example.com/">Example</a></li>
<li id="helper2"><a href="https://example.com/">Example</a>
</li></ul>

Modified JS below.
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById("holder").onmouseover = function(){mouseOver()};
    document.getElementById("holder").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
    function mouseOver() { 
    document.getElementById("helper1").style.display=="block";}
    function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("helper").style.display=="none";}
</script>
```

This should work.

Comment: So far it didnt work. I editted my question, as i didnt name all the classes that are included in the html. Maybe that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

**getElementsByClassName** will return an array with all elements with class *helper*. You need to change the display of each of those elements, something like this:

```
    function mouseOver() { 
         var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("helper");
         myList.forEach(function(item){
             item.style.display="block";
         });
    }
```

Comment: So far it didnt work. I editted my question, as i didnt name all the classes that are included in the html. Maybe that makes a difference?